# Count of orders in last 24 by hour

Tags: php, database, laravel-5.1

I have an order table which has created_at and I was wondering how I can take the last 24 hours orders and group them by hour and show the total orders for that hour.

```
$hourlyOrders = Order::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))->count();
```

I guess I then need to groupBy hour in some way? I just need a count of the hourly orders.

EDIT:

So if I checked now there would be order totals from 9-10am, 8am-9am, 7am-8am back through 24 iterations but it is dependent on when the query is run…if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This :

```
$hourlyOrders = Order::where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))
              ->groupBy(\DB::raw('HOUR(created_at)'))
              ->count();
```

**EDIT :**

```
$orders = DB::table('Order') // write your table name
         ->selectRaw('count(order_id) as total_orders')) // use your field for count
         ->where('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->subDays(1))
         ->groupBy(\DB::raw('HOUR(created_at)'))
         ->get();
```

Comment: It seems to be only returning the total for the day not as a count by hour over the last 24 hours...thanks for taking time out to help though

Comment: Hi Yasin,

If you change ->select to ->selectRaw it works perfectly :)

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Plain SQL to group by the result by hour would be:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Order
GROUP BY hour( created_at );
```